# Why does my webservice reply with ok status but doesn't fill the datatable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, datatables

I am using server side to do heavy processing for jQuery datatables because data can be more than 10,000 but I am getting an error.

I am using pure jQuery with c# .asmx webservices

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter
>   'UserName' for row 0, column 0.

I checked the return status and it's OK 200 and also JSON data is returned which I checked in response section but still the above error.

Code:

```
function show()
{                
    $('#example').DataTable
    (
        {
            //data: data,
            columns: 
            [                    
                {'data': 'UserName'},
                {'data': 'Password'},
            ],
            bServerSide: true,
            sAjaxSource: 'http://localhost:8373/himher.asmx/getUsers',
            sServerMethod: 'post'
        });              
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```

I have just put the relevant code above.

c# webmethod:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public void getUsers(int iDisplayLength, int iDisplayStart, int iSortCol_0, string sSortDir_0, string sSearch)
{
    try
    {
        basicoperation bop = new basicoperation();
        DataTable dt;

        dt = bop.getUsers(iDisplayLength, iDisplayStart, iSortCol_0, sSortDir_0, sSearch); // fetching users

        dt.TableName = "usersDT";  // a datatable must be named before serialization

        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0]; 

        string jsonDataTable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt); //a  data table must be serialized before transmitting

        var retObj = new
        {
            iTotalRecords = dr["TotalCount"].ToString(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords= dt.Rows.Count,
            aaData = jsonDataTable
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(retObj)); // converting a .net object to JSON

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }    

}
```

returns:

```
{"iTotalRecords":"19","iTotalDisplayRecords":5,"aaData":"[{\"RowNum\":2,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":39,\"UserName\":\"adsbkj\",\"Password\":\"23123\"},{\"RowNum\":3,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":40,\"UserName\":\"adsbkj\",\"Password\":\"23123\"},{\"RowNum\":4,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":37,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"23\"},{\"RowNum\":5,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":2,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"asdasd\"},{\"RowNum\":6,\"TotalCount\":19,\"Id\":5,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"asda\"}]"}
```

Comment: `DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'UserName' for row 0, column 0.` Which line shows that? Please point us to the specific line. If there is an exception, please include a screenshot of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

it either passed a null value of a not valid one.for your reference 
https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

Comment: It's just a username, trying to bind with what JSON returned.

Answer (score 0):

You converting data in `aaData` to JSON format twice with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)` which results in incorrect data.

I'm not C# expert, but this should help.

```
var retObj = new
{
    iTotalRecords = dr["TotalCount"].ToString(),
    iTotalDisplayRecords= dt.Rows.Count,
    aaData = dt
};
```